# B2C Custom Policy - Redirect login error back to app

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

During the b2c login flow, if a user cancels a step then he is automatically redirected to the `api.error` / `globalexception` page.

I would like to redirect the user back to my application, ideally this would result in an `OnAuthenticationFailed` event in the `OpenIdConnectOptions`.

I might use the same policy with multiple redirect-URIs, so using javascript to redirect is not really feasible.

Does anyone know if this can be achieved?

Comment: Are you sure? Default behavior when clicking the 'Cancel' button on a self asserted page is to redirect back to your application with an error code.

Comment: You might be using [Development Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights), causing the error not to be sent back to the app - which is the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you @JasSuri-MSFT! That was my issue, I must have missed that in the documentation. If you add your comment as an answer i will mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @jas-suri-msft for providing the answer in the comment.
When setting `DeploymentMode="Development"` in the custom policies, canceling a flow will show you the `globalexception` error page instead of redirecting back to the app and triggering the `OnAuthenticationFailed` callback.
In order to enable redirection you should use `DeploymentMode="Production"`.